# How to fix ESLint error by Reformat Code command in RubyMine

Tags: webstorm, eslint, rubymine, nuxt.js

I want to fix ESLint error and warning by `Reformat Code` command in RubyMine.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46099408/1536527), but the answer uses `Fix ESLint problems` command. (I want to use always same shortcut key for code formatting)

To add style rules I opened `.eslintrc.js` in my nuxt project and run `Apply ESLint Code Style Rules` command, but it didn't change behavior.

How can I fix ESLint problems by `Reformat Code` command?

This is my `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended'
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only core ESLint rules are applied when importing code style settings from ESLint. In particular, rules from `eslint-plugin-vue` are not imported. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34649#focus=streamItem-27-3053601.0-0 for more info.

So, you have you either adjust code style settings manually or use *Fix ESLint problems* to format your files