# eslint problem with firebase functions and idea

Tags: javascript, firebase, intellij-idea, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I reinstalled Intellij Idea and opened my vuejs/firebase project. I am able to see eslint notifications in IDE editor but inside functions directory in any js file I don't see any notifications. But when I try to deploy firebase --only functions I see lots of errors from prettier.

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /home/madcap/Projects/Alex/functions
>   eslint .

```
/home/madcap/Projects/Alex/functions/index.js
  10:3   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  12:1   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  13:3   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  14:1   error  Replace `····` with `··`                    prettier/prettier
  15:1   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  16:1   error  Replace `····` with `··`                    prettier/prettier
  17:1   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  19:3   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  20:5   error  Delete `····`                               prettier/prettier
  21:1   error  Replace `············` with `······`        prettier/prettier
  22:1   error  Replace `········` with `····`              prettier/prettier
  23:1   error  Delete `····`                               prettier/prettier
  25:5   error  Delete `····`                               prettier/prettier
  26:1   error  Replace `············` with `······`        prettier/prettier
  27:1   error  Delete `········`                           prettier/prettier
  28:1   error  Replace `················` with `········`  prettier/prettier
  29:1   error  Replace `················` with `········`  prettier/prettier
  30:7   error  Delete `······`                             prettier/prettier
  31:5   error  Delete `····`                               prettier/prettier
  33:1   error  Replace `········` with `····`              prettier/prettier
  35:5   error  Delete `····`                               prettier/prettier
  36:1   error  Replace `········` with `····`              prettier/prettier
  37:1   error  Replace `············` with `······`        prettier/prettier
  38:7   error  Delete `······`                             prettier/prettier
  39:1   error  Replace `················` with `········`  prettier/prettier
  40:1   error  Delete `··········`                         prettier/prettier
  41:11  error  Delete `··········`                         prettier/prettier
  42:1   error  Replace `················` with `········`  prettier/prettier
  43:1   error  Replace `············` with `······`        prettier/prettier
  44:1   error  Replace `········` with `····`              prettier/prettier
  46:1   error  Delete `····`                               prettier/prettier
  48:5   error  Delete `····`                               prettier/prettier
  49:3   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  51:1   error  Replace `····` with `··`                    prettier/prettier
  52:1   error  Replace `········` with `····`              prettier/prettier
  53:1   error  Replace `············` with `······`        prettier/prettier
  54:1   error  Replace `············` with `······`        prettier/prettier
  55:7   error  Delete `······`                             prettier/prettier
  56:1   error  Delete `····`                               prettier/prettier
  57:5   error  Delete `····`                               prettier/prettier
  61:1   error  Delete `⏎··`                                prettier/prettier
  63:3   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  65:3   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  66:1   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  68:3   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  70:1   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  71:3   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  73:1   error  Replace `····` with `··`                    prettier/prettier
  74:1   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  76:3   error  Delete `··`                                 prettier/prettier
  77:2   error  Insert `⏎`                                  prettier/prettier

✖ 51 problems (51 errors, 0 warnings)
  51 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/madcap/.npm/_logs/2020-02-18T02_50_25_483Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

I've tried to reinstall firebase functions by deleting the folder and fully reinstall it with overwriting everything (firebase init functions).

I have .eslintrc.json file that has been created automatically

I have "eslint": "^5.12.0", in dev dependencies of package.json

I just don't know what happened

Comment: What's in your eslintrc? Sounds like you need to have eslint ignore the node_modules directory.

Comment: it's a standard eslintrc.json created when 'firebase init functions'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make WebStorm format code according to eslint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735890/how-to-make-webstorm-format-code-according-to-eslint)

Answer (score 0):

The intellij eslint configuration is not properly configured to use the project's eslint file. So it is using the default one that has a different setting for indetation spaces.

Here you have the official guides to do it:

[IntelliJ - How to configure prettier](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prettier.html)

[IntelliJ - How to configure eslint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eslint.html)

Comment: Didn't help. I've tried to reinstall functions without eslint option but I'm getting this error when deploying: missing script: lint

Comment: That's because in package.json file there is not a lint script. You need to add ir there. 
`{ 
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint.js"
  }
}`